# warning : function created with compilation error

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Table EMP has ENAME as attribute.The following function gives error:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SET ECHO ON
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION count_emp(e_name varchar(20))
RETURN integer IS 
total integer;
BEGIN 
SELECT count(*) into total 
FROM DEPARTMENTS
where ENAME = e_name;
RETURN total; 
END; 
/
```

> warning:function created with compilation error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run `show errors;` to see what compilation errors are.

The parameter's datatype should be specified without length. Also, use `varchar2` instead of `varchar`.

From [Oracle site](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1822):

> The VARCHAR datatype is synonymous with the VARCHAR2 datatype. To avoid possible changes in behavior, always use the VARCHAR2 datatype to store variable-length character strings.

Try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION count_emp(e_name varchar2) -- here
RETURN integer IS 
total integer;
BEGIN 
SELECT count(*) into total 
FROM DEPARTMENTS
where ENAME = e_name;
RETURN total; 
END; 
/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you care about table `EMP`, you should use it in the function.

I would write this as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION count_emp (
    in_e_name varchar2
)
RETURN integer IS 
    v_total integer;
BEGIN 
    SELECT COUNT(*) into v_total 
    FROM EMP e
    WHERE e.ENAME = in_e_name;

    RETURN v_total; 
END;
```

Notes:

- Oracle will compile functions and stored procedures even when the objects don't (yet) exist.  This is considered a "feature".
- Use naming conventions to distinguish parameters and variables from columns.  This is using `in_` for the input parameters and `v_` for the local variables.
- Qualify all column name references.  This further reduces the possibility of collision between a variable and column name.
- You don't need a length for `varchar2()` inputs (which is preferable to `varchar()`, although perhaps one day, Oracle will cave to the standard).