# Getting an error while creating a PL/SQL function

Tags: oracle, plsql, stored-functions

Question is : Function: Create a Function named 'find_credit_card' which takes card_no as input and returns the holder name of type varchar.

- Function name:   find_credit_card
- Input Parameter:  card_no with data type as varchar
- Output variable : holder_name with data type as varchar(30)
- Hint: Add '/' after the end statement

Refer to the schema.

My code :-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_credit_card(card_no IN VARCHAR2(255))
   RETURN VARCHAR 
IS
   holder_name VARCHAR(255)
BEGIN

   SELECT name 
     INTO  holder_name 
     from credit_card 
    where card_number = card_no;
   RETURN(holder_name);
END;
/
```

Warning : Function created with compilation errors.

Comment: What development tool are you using? You will need to familiarise yourself with whatever feature it uses to display compilation errors. If it doesn't have one, `select * from user_errors where name = 'FIND_CREDIT_CARD';`

Comment: It's a bit odd that you are instructed to use a datatype that [Oracle documentation explicitly says not to use](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-DF7E10FC-A461-4325-A295-3FD4D150809E).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [warning : function created with compilation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43030959/warning-function-created-with-compilation-error)

Answer (score 0):

Error(s) you got can be reviewed in SQL*Plus by running `show err`:

```
Warning: Function created with compilation errors.

SQL> show err
Errors for FUNCTION FIND_CREDIT_CARD:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
1/46     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the
         following:
         := . ) , @ % default character
         The symbol ":=" was substituted for "(" to continue.

5/1      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN" when expecting one of
         the following:
         := ; not null default character

SQL>
```

Alternatively, query `user_errors`:

```
select line, position, text
from user_errors
where name = 'FIND_CREDIT_CARD';
```

Oracle says that there are two errors:

- first one means that function's parameter shouldn't have size, so - not `card_no in varchar2(255)` but only `card_no in varchar2`
- another one means that you *forgot* to terminate line where local variable was declared (missing semi-colon at the end of that line):

  ```
  holder_name VARCHAR(255);
  ```

---

However, consider *inheriting* datatype from column description. If it is ever changed, you wouldn't have to modify your code.

Furthermore, it would be good if you distinguish parameters and local variables from column names. How? Use prefixes, e.g. `par_` for parameters, `l_` or `v_` for local variables.

Also, Oracle recommends us to use `varchar2`, not `varchar`.

Finally, that function might look like this:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_credit_card
  2    (par_card_number IN credit_card.card_number%TYPE)
  3  RETURN credit_card.name%type
  4  IS
  5    l_holder_name credit_card.name%TYPE;
  6  BEGIN
  7    SELECT name
  8      INTO l_holder_name
  9      FROM credit_card
 10      WHERE card_number = par_card_number;
 11
 12    RETURN l_holder_name;
 13  END;
 14  /

Function created.

SQL> select find_credit_card('HR123456789') holder from dual;

HOLDER
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Littlefoot

SQL>
```